# Changing iAd position programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, iad, cgrect

I have a medium sized iAd frame (300x250) that I want to center in my view.  Let me first say that I stuck it right in the view controller, ran the simulator, and it showed up no problem.  I then added auto constraints to center horizontally and vertically.  On the storyboard preview it worked, but when I ran it in the actual simulator the ad was nowhere to be found.  I outputted a success statement, so it did load and everything, but it didn't appear.  Removing the constraints rectified it.

So I tried to do it programmatically.  I created the necessary delegates and everything, and code I'm seeing for how to do it is very similar to others, so I have no idea why this isn't working.  No matter what values I put into CGRect the Ad just looks the same everywhere.

**Code:**

```
import UIKit
import iAd

class replayAdViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var bannerView: ADBannerView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    bannerView!.delegate = self
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!)
{
    println("success, banner loaded")

    var width = self.view.frame.width
    var height = self.view.frame.height

    banner.frame = CGRectMake(width, height, 300, 250)

    self.view.addSubview(banner) //Add banner to view (Ad loaded)
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError
    error: NSError!)
{
        println("failed to load ad, removed")
        println(error)
        //banner.removeFromSuperview() //Remove the banner (No ad)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

I have tried moving the CGRect statement out of the function and into viewDidLoad and using bannerView.frame, etc.  I'm guessing I'm somehow linking the banner with the properties of CGRect or something incorrectly, but there are no errors so I don't know.  Also I don't get why the auto constraints mess it up with just a vertical and horizontal center, but either issue being resolved would really help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: I also realize to center it would have to be the height and width divided by 2, but that part was irrelevant since no matter what I stuck in there, the position would remain the same.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your outlets are setup correctly, You should position the ad in `didMoveToView` like this: `bannerView.center = self.view.center`  Also, in `didFailToReceiveAdWithError`, it works better if you hide the banner: `bannerView.hidden = true`. You don't have to have this line `self.view.addSubview(banner)` because you add the banner to the view in the storyboard. The size of the banner can be set in the storyboard too using constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the response as such.  However, I did find a solution.  Threw out all the constraints and after adding the Ad delegate, I simply used code to create and move the Ad as so:

var adView = ADBannerView(adType: ADAdType.MediumRectangle)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    adView.frame = CGRectZero
    adView.delegate = self
    adView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.adView.frame.size.height, self.adView.frame.size.width)

    adView.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.size.height / 2)

    self.view.addSubview(adView) }
```

Not really sure where things went wrong to begin with.  I tried creating a button using an outlet and moving it in viewDidLoad, which also started not working, but I resolved that by doing the positioning code in viewDidLayoutSubviews...so maybe if I'm creating an outlet AND using code to move that, I have to use that particular method and not viewDidLoad.  Maybe that was the error, but either way this was a solution.